# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I was able to run the project using the command line, but from last 1 day I am not able to run the command from the command line However using GUI the project is running fine...
[image]

```
    C:\Users\tester\PycharmProjects\Selenium\SampleProjects\POMProjectDemo\Tests>py
thon login.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 6, in <module>
    from SampleProjects.POMProjectDemo.Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SampleProjects'

C:\Users\tester\PycharmProjects\Selenium\SampleProjects\POMProjectDemo\Tests>py
thon -m unittest login.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: login (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\
loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\tester\PycharmProjects\Selenium\SampleProjects\POMProjectDemo\
Tests\login.py", line 6, in <module>
    from SampleProjects.POMProjectDemo.Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SampleProjects'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

[![Tests/login.py

import time
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from SampleProjects.POMProjectDemo.Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
from SampleProjects.POMProjectDemo.Pages.homePage import HomePage
import HtmlTestRunner
from SampleProjects.POMProjectDemo.Utility.XLUtil import getData

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):


        @classmethod

    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_login_valid(self):
        path = 'c:/Users/mahmood/PycharmProjects/Selenium_automaton/Login.xlsx'
        # global path
        driver = self.driver
        row = getData.getRowCount(path,'Sheet1')
        for r in range(2,row+1):
          driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
          userN = getData.readData(path,'Sheet1',r,1)
          passW = getData.readData(path,'Sheet1',r,2)
```

Same code was running fine, what changes I have done not able to debug it.

Comment: Is `SampleProjects` part of your project's source code? It looks like you've got imports that extend above the project.

Comment: added the project structure, SampleProject is the root directory..

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that your project isn't visible to Python where you're running it. Try running it from the Selenium directory. If that doesn't work, try to find another way to add them to the module search path.

Comment: check your `$PATH` variable, and see if `SampleProject` is reachable by the python interpreter from there.